# Is "when I was nine-month pregnant" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage

I heard someone said on the radio:

> "... when I was nine-month pregnant."

I might've misheard anyway, given my non-native weak ear. As I understand, the hyphened word combination usually works like an adjective. For example, an 8-year-old boy. Can it also be like an adverb to modify an adjective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You did not hear a hyphen on the radio, and you might have misheard 'month'. When using a quantifying phrase to modify an adjective, we use no hyphens, and the units are singular or plural as appropriate. *One hour early; two kilos overweight; nine months pregnant; six months dead; two hours late; forty years old; three weeks overdue.*

Comment: It's worth noting that we can also use a singular time unit, with hyphens, when we modify a noun instead of an adjective: _It was a ten-year crisis; I took a five-week vacation; we watched a three-hour movie; that is a forty-year-old building; it was a nine-month pregnancy_. I suppose, though, that there could be a _ten-second pregnant pause_.